# How to open Bar code scanning view in UIWebView OR WkWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

- I have query regarding Bar code scanning in WebView.
- iOS version is 11.2 and swift version is 4.

[I have shared iPad screen sort with error message with you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPxKF.png)

- If I open URL in Safari then barcode scanning is working, but when I tried to open same URL in Webview (UIWebView OR WKWebView), It's shows me an error then **No Video Input Devices Error**

[Here I share screen short of bar code scanning working in perfect condition in SAFARI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKvQE.jpg)

- In above screen sort, there is one red icon shows in address bar, this indicate for bar code scanning permission.
- I have also tried in SFSafariViewController, but still I face same issue.
- I have added all permission in info.plist
  [Here my info.plist permission screen sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hOZa.png)
- Please assist me if you find any solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: looking for too